# With androidx.appcompat library FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, adapter, android-adapter

When upgrading `build tool version` and `target SDK version` to API 28 we have to use new support libraries with `androidx` prefix. I have replaced all libs with new  libs here they are

```
 // Libs for newer API 28
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Now FirebaseRecyclerAdapter from the import below, asking me to extend my ViewHolder class from `android.support.v7`.

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

And has this suggestion

> Type parameter
>   'com.domain_name.app_name.FriendsFragment.FindFriendsViewHolder' is
>   not within its bound; should extend
>   'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder'

I'm extending `ViewHolder` from API 28 with the below import

```
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

User Sam Stern on github suggested to add below two lines in `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

But with these lines, my adapter class do not recognize `onCreateViewHolder` method and says "Method 'onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup, int)' is never used".

Please let me know how to make it work with new libs from `androidx`. I will be thankful for this.

Comment: Libarary doesnot have update to androidx, you can check the code here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java it still imports from support library not androidx.

Comment: Hmm so should I create a new issue on lib's github page?

Comment: Btw it is not mandatory to use androidx libraries if target sdk is 28. you can still use support libraries v28.x.x

Comment: you can also pull and do the modifications yourself and include library as module.